# jQuery Accordion disabled section icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a jQuery accordion and with some help I managed to figure out most of my issues but now I have one that I could not figure out.

My accordion looks like this

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
     active: true,
     animate: false,
     collapsible: true,
     heightStyle: "content",
     icons: icons
 });
```

and I have 2 icons defined for opened and closed sections. 
I also have in my accordion some disabled sections that are closed and cannot be expanded. As far as I can see it's either all icons for all sections or none at all. 
Is there any way of removing the icon for just the disabled sections ?

Comment: Can you share an HTML snippet of the accordion.

Comment: Where is `icons` defined in your code?